# IF formula excel-2019

Tags: basic, excel-2019

IF(Database!L2="male, female",Database!N2,"")
Salam to every one,
The above formula can't working properly, I want ot get data from one sheet to other sheet( if L2 column equal to male or female get data from N2 column otherwise cell must empty.

Thanks

Comment: You need an `OR` function. Currently you are literally comparing to `"male,female"`

Comment: Dear Sir! The below formula works properly but for the empty cells, it comes #value! (=IF(S4=0," ",IF(E4-S4>=3,"improved",IF(E4-S4<=4,"Not Improved")))). I want to the S4 and E4 =0 the result comes empty means it comes blank but with me shows #VALUE! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
=IF(OR(Database!L2="male",Database!L2="female"),Database!N2,"")
```

Comment: Dear Sir! The below formula works properly but for the empty cells, it comes #value! (=IF(S4=0," ",IF(E4-S4>=3,"improved",IF(E4-S4<=4,"Not Improved")))). I want to the S4 and E4 =0 the result comes empty means it comes blank but with me shows #VALUE! thanks in advance

Comment: @Javid In your recent comment(s) you seem to be asking a different question. If the current question about `IF(Database!L2="male, female",Database!N2,"")` got answered satisfactory, then please click on the accept arrow. Next you can post a new question about whatever trouble it is you have with `(=IF(S4=0," ",IF(E4-S4>=3,"improved",IF(E4-S4<=4,"Not Improved"))))`.